# Javascript: Why do I need to define self invoking anonymous function if I'm already using an external function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Why do I need to define self invoking anonymous function if I'm already using an external function?

Lets use those simple examples...

Why this is working:

```
var countDown=60;

function myTimer()
{
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=countDown;
    countDown--;
}

var stopper=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
```

but this not :

```
var countDown=60;

function myTimer()
{
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=countDown;
    countDown--;
}

var stopper=setInterval(myTimer(),1000); //self invoking anonymous function removed
```

It looks wierd to me since I'm already call to an external function so why do I need to do it WITHIN self invoking anonymous function firsthand?

Comment: try 
var stopper=setInterval(myTimer,1000);
without ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is working because you're passing a function as the first parameter to `setInterval` function. That's what `setInterval` expects.

On your second example, you're not passing a function reference, but you're passing the result of the invocation of the function: `setInterval(myTimer(),1000)`.

You need to pass the function itself, so you need to do this:

`setInterval(myTimer, 1000)`